# how to use pug templating engine with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pug, jsx

I have did the following in order to integrate pug with a newly created reactjs application :

**`1.`** Create a fresh reactjs app using **`create-react-app`**

**`2.`** Then I followed the instruction from [**babel-plugin-transform-react-pug**](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug) to install the plugin as mentioned in pugjs official site.

I used `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-pug` to install the above plugin.
Then I've created a `.babelrc` file in my root directory  and add the following in `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-pug",
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

**`3.`** In my react app I've created an App component like the following :

```
import React from "react"

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return pug`
      div
        h1 My Component
        p This is my component using pug.
    `;
  }
}

export default App;
```

But whenever I run the app usng **`npm start`**, I get the error message

> ./src/App.js   Line 5:  'pug' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I haven't done this, but whenever doing something like `pug\`(...)` I have needed to import that package. Give this a try: install and import 'pug'.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to importing pug? from where I should import it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug

Comment: I did import pug from 'pug' and it is showing error on startup

Comment: The official documentation should have a clear guideline on how to do this stuff.

Comment: What's the error? Yes for some reason a lot of developers assume you have their secret knowledge so they don't actually tell you how to install it, just the later steps.

Comment: I was able to make it work. Included it as an answer to this question. Hope somebody will find it useful

Comment: @AL-zami , I have taken your awesome step by step instructions and created a github repo that illustrates how to enable pug templating in an ejected create-react-app. https://github.com/SydBal/cra-ejected-pug Thank you for you guide!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work.The actual documentation for integrating pug with react was not so helpful.But I finally figured out how to do this. This is what worked for me :

1. Create a react app using : `create-ract-app puginreact1`
2. after that `npm start` ( to check if everything is ok)
3. You need to eject the create-react-app. so run `npm run eject`. There are other options, but I went with eject.
4. Then `npm start` again in order to check if everything is ok.
5. You need to include [babel plugin](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug) so that react recognize pug. So run `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-pug`
6. In `package.json` ( instead of creating `.babelrc` file in root directory ) include the following babel configuration. If you already have one just include the presets and plugins properties in the existing bable config in `package.json`

`"babel": {  "presets": [ "react-app" ], //already included "plugins": [ "transform-react-pug", "transform-react-jsx" ]  },`

7. If you run npm start now you may get the following error

> can not find module "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

8. Above mentioned missing [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) can be found here
9. Install it :  `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`
10. After that, if you run the app, you will get the following error

> pug is undefined no-undef

11. As reactjs by default use `[eslint-plugin-react][3]`,  do the following from  [eslint-plugin-react-pug](https://github.com/ezhlobo/eslint-plugin-react-pug) documentation

frist, `npm install eslint --save-dev`

then, `npm install eslint-plugin-react-pug --save-dev`

12. Then in `package.json` modify `eslintConfig`. ( you could also use `.eslintrc` in root directory )

    "eslintConfig": {
    "plugins": [ "react-pug"],
    "extends": [ "react-app", "plugin:react-pug/all" ]
    }
13. Then `npm start`

Now pug templateing should work with react js. At least it worked for me.